# Cannot authenticate to mongo from outside replicaSet

Tags: mongodb

I have created a new ReplicaSet as described in the following Tutorials:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-auth/

My config of a node looks like this:

```
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true
fork=true
dbpath=/home/mongo/data
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
auth=true
replSet=rs01
keyFile=/home/mongo/key/keyfile
```

The ReplicaSet works as expected:

```
rs01:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs01",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T07:57:50.727Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "mongo04.mydomain.de:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 495477,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1427742130, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-30T19:02:10Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-01T07:57:49.204Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-01T07:57:49.210Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "syncingTo" : "mongo03.mydomain.de:27017",
                    "configVersion" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "mongo02.mydomain.de:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 500568,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1427742130, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-30T19:02:10Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-01T07:57:49.196Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-01T07:57:49.222Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "syncingTo" : "mongo03.mydomain.de:27017",
                    "configVersion" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "mongo03.mydomain.de:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 501402,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1427742130, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-30T19:02:10Z"),
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1427379457, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-03-26T14:17:37Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 3,
                    "self" : true
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I've created a new database "testdb" and added a user "test" with roles "readWrite" and "dbAdmin".
I can connect from any Node of the ReplicatSet to any Node inside the ReplicaSet:

```
[root@mongo04 ~]# mongo -u test -p --host mongo03.mydomain.de testdb
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongo03.mydomain.de:27017/testdb
rs01:PRIMARY>
```

But I can't connect from a Server outside the ReplicaSet:

```
[root@mongo01 ~]# mongo -u test -p --host mongo03.mydomain.de testdb
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
Enter password:
connecting to: mongo03.mydomain.de:27017/testdb
2015-04-01T10:12:30.958+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

I'va searched a lot, but I didn't find any reason why I can't connect from a Server outside the ReplicaSet.

Has anyone any ideas, what I've forgotten or made wrong in the config?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to `mongo03.mydomain.de` prior to setting up authentication? May well be that the connection is rejected by the firewall and the error message is misleading. Try to connect too the "foobar" DB and see what happens.

Comment: I've checked that first by issuing a telnet-session:
`[root@mongo01 ~]# telnet mongo03.mydomain.de 27017
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to mongo03.mydomain.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
`

Comment: so it's not a firewall-problem

Comment: Try connecting from the outside host using shell 3.0.1 - the version you're using in the replica set. The default auth method changed between 2.6 and 3.0.

Comment: That solved my Problem!!!
Thanks very much!!!
For detail: Version 3.0.1 uses SCRAM_SHA_1 as authenticationMechanism, Version 2.6 uses MONGODB-CR as default.
All clients I've tested use the MONGODB-CR as default and at a few of them it is possible to change the authenticationMechanism.